# Two ARP entries if installing MSI first and then a bundle containing the MSI

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

Why do I get two AddRemoveProgram entries if I install the `setup.msi` first, and then install the `bundle.exe` containing the `setup.msi`. Here is the Chain in my bundle.

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist"/>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.MsiProject.TargetDir)Setup.msi" />
</Chain>
```

The `setup.msi` has a hard-coded ProductCode that was extracted from the `bundle.exe` using **`dark -x`**. Shouldn't `bundle.exe` detect the already installed `setup.msi` and skip the installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first entry is for the MSI; the second for the bundle. An `MsiPackage` element has a `Visible` attribute that controls whether Burn causes the package to have its own ARP entry visible or not. The default is "no" so in some cases, but not yours, it would result in the two entries.

Yes, Burn does not reinstall packages that are already installed.

Burn is a package manager so it'll always install/uninstall and register/unregister itself. When multiple bundles contain the same packages, Burn figures out which to leave when uninstalling a bundle. Of course, some, like NetFx40Redist, are marked as permanent so the bundle will never uninstall them.

Again, if you'd rather not see an ARP entry for the MSI, be sure to the MsiPackage/@Visible element isn't set to "yes".

Comment: Ahh, you are absolute right! How dumb was I totally not aware of this. Appreciates!

Comment: fyi, `@Visible="no"` is [the default](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html)

Comment: @Hall72215 Thanks. Of course, it would have no effect if the MSI was already installed. So, prior installation by other means completely explains why the question asker sees it.

Comment: Yes, your core answer is right (`The first entry is for the MSI; the second for the bundle`).  Some of your explanation is misleading though: unless the MSI installs itself as hidden when run alone, you will always see two entries when you install the MSI before the bundle (even when `@Visible="no"`).  And with his original bundle, if he installed the bundle first then there would only be one entry.